# where is the scroll bar coming from and how can i remove it?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

is there a way i can remove the scrollbars (horizontal and vertical) from my website?

Comment: What every is setting your dynamic height is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about horizontal scrollbar then you can use the following css:

```
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It's just a quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

in your css state "overflow:hidden" for the appropriate container (may be html)

but be aware, that you may change this later on if you have scrolling areas somewhere

Answer (score 0):

As said above, doing overflow-x:hidden can work, but if the time ever comes when someone **does** need a scrollbar, it then won't appear. It's best to tackle the problem by finding out what's causing it. It seems to me your canvas element has the extra width. Right now you have the canvas element wrapped inside a div. That div has a width of 100%. Try setting the width of the canvas to 100% in your CSS and see if that solves the problem, because for some reason it has a width higher than 100%.